# Reading data from memory in C#

Tags: c#, sql, for-loop, memory, entity

I am working on something which requires to read data from a file. As you can see below, I am going through filelist with a for cycle, searching for that specific hexadecimal character and I am replacing the character with and empty space. 
Later on, I overwrite the original file with lines, since lines now does not have the hexadecimal character but I am not allowed to overwrite the original character. I am also not allowed to save lines as a new file in the source directory (in which the original file is).

```
var fileList = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

foreach (var file in fileList)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

    for(var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (lines[i].Contains("\u001A"))
        {
            lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("\u001A", " ");
        }
    }

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
    var grkFile = new GenericRkFile<FileTypes.FinancialAdvisor, FileTypes.Plan, FileTypes.PlanFund, FileTypes.Header, FileTypes.Trailer>();
    grkFile.LoadData(file);
}
```

Since `grkFile.LoadData()` is a file, I can't pass lines as a value. 
My question is, can I somehow save lines as a file in memory or something like that and use it to pass onto grkFile.LoadData() ?

Comment: You won't be able to use a [`MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) unless `GenericRkFile.LoadData()` has an overload that accepts a stream. But what's stopping you from writing the data to a file in the Windows temp folder and using that instead?

Comment: Could you share signature of `LoadData` method?

Comment: If you cannot change signature of `LoadData` you can create file on temporary location load it and then remove it... you have already some helper method like `Path.GetTempFileName`...

Comment: I can't change or add anything in LoadData. It's a class with methods from which a lot of other classes inherit. Perhaps it would be best to save lines as a file in a temp location...

Comment: Can you please write your comment as a reply because I can't label it as the answer since it's a comment? @Lepijohnny

Comment: Thanks, I have written an answer. Nice that you have solved your problem. @Novica Josifovski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you depends on the `API` which you cannot change option can be to create temporary file on the temporary location, fill it with right data, load it and then remove it. `.NET` provides some helper methods which can make your life even easier. These are located within `System.IO namespace`. This one is quite useful to create temporary file within the temporary user folder:

```
Path.GetTempFileName()
```

For more information you can look at: [Sytem.IO.Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx)